# C++ , valgrind operator new(unsigned int)

Tags: c++, valgrind

For instance, I want to model something like a chain of cars and each car has a pointer to the next car. I have a Road-Class defining one special police-Car and some member functions to search for some (int) element, stored in the "el"-variable of each Car. And then I want to insert a Car with a certain number.

```
class Road
{
public:

    int size_road;
    Car* police;

public:

    bool insert(int el1);
    pair<bool,int> search(int el2);


};
struct Car {
public:
    int el;
 Car  ,  *right;
// Car(){}
  Car(int a1,, Car *c1): el(a1), right(c1){}

};
```

member_function:

```
bool Road::insert(int el1){

    if (size_road==0){      

    vector<Car*> cars;  
    Car* a;    

    for (int i=0; i<=size_road;i++){
        if (i==0){
             a =new Car(el1, NULL, NULL);
            cars.push_back(a);
        }
            else {
                Car* point=cars[i-1];
        a =new Car(el1, point, NULL);           
        cars.push_back(a)
            }       
    }

    size_road+=1;


    }
```

mail:
Road road88;
road.size_road=0;
road88.insert(5);
I run valgrind and it showed me the following error:

```
==9188==    at 0x402B9B4: operator new(unsigned int) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==9188==    by 0x8048AC1: Road::insert(int) (in /home/tonja/Desktop/HH/1/test)
```

What does it mean? Why it is a problem to assign a new Car some value of integer type?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 0) valgrind is sometimes not well suited to C++, you might have a false positive 1) please post actual code or an actual testcase. The code as is does not even compile 2) why not a standard container like `std::list`?

Comment: You're only showing us the stack trace that's reported with the error. What is the error? Perhaps it's a memory leak, which is likely since you never delete the cars you're creating with `new`? In any case, use `vector<Car>` and don't use `new` unless you really need to (which you don't here).

Answer (score 2):

In the code you show, the Car is never deleted.

Comment: I edited my code, I want Car-objects to exist till the end of the program.

Comment: You have to delete them at some point. Otherwise valgrind will keep reporting a memory leak.

Comment: @Tonja: What speaks against standard containers?